# Flutter : Cannot build the apk release file

Tags: android, flutter, apk, android-manifest, release

I want to build a release apk file for my flutter app. I use firebase so I added the android.permission.internet to the AndroidManifest.xml before the application tag. I don't understand why it's still not working.

android.manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.example">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    
    <application
    ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried to remove the two lines below that need an internet connection and it worked.

```
Future<void> main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
   runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Any ideas? Please help.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing when building the apk?

Comment: When I run : flutter build apk --release, there's no error. But when I launch the app on my real device, there's just a white screen(the launch screen)

Comment: And what do you see from logcat when you open the application?

Comment: If you mean when I run: flutter run --release, the app works fine, but it's when I create the apk file by running: flutter build apk --release that the app doesn't work. Any ideas of what it could be ?

Comment: I am referring to when the application launches on your physical device. You can see the output of that in logcat.

Comment: The first error when the application lauches is : E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)

Comment: There you go - you have an exception that relates to Firebase. I would google that exception and see why it is caused. If I were you, I would add a concise and relevant code snippet from your project so we can better understand what you are doing wrong.